# Kinect - Calculating Surface Area

Tags: distance, kinect, area, depth

I'd like to be able to calculate the surface area of objects seen by the depth camera. Is there an easy way to do this? For example if the kinect is seeing a player I need to calculate how much surface it is covering.

If there is no such functions existing, I can calculate by creating multiple squares with coordinate (x,y) (x+1,y) (x, y+1) (x+1, y+1) and taking into consideration the z value. But I'm not sure how to get the distance in mm or cm between pixels in the x or y axis.

Thanks